# How to build Azure Data Factory and Azure functions for file validation check and sending error mail

Tags: python, azure-functions, sendgrid

I have a Azure Data Factory Copy activity within a pipeline.
The copy activity is working. I have 2 questions.
The first Q is how to build Azure data factory or Azure functions to execute any processes below.

1. Copy uploaded csv files or excel file to another conteiner.
2. Execute validation check of azure function for that coded by python.
3. Send the mail included error messages as attached file generated by the validation check by Azure send grid for SMTP.
4. If there is no problem with the validation check, copy that file to  SQL database table.

Thank you a lot for your cooporations in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to your questions below as I understood. Feel free to clarify if you need something else or more details.

> Copy uploaded csv files or excel file to another conteiner.

Use [Copy Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) with source blob as Input and Target blob as Output

> Thank you. I got it. also I I could implement this.

> Execute validation check of azure function for that coded by python

Use [Azure Function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) in Data Factory to call your http triggered
function (assuming you meant validation check of the file you are uploading/copying?)

> Yes, I do. the file is same file which I uploaded and copied. How can I use a Message Queue trriger ? I hope to use a trriger of copy complete queue because of big file.

You won't need a queue to handle yourself. You can use inbuilt Blob [Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger)  which will make your life easier.

> Send the mail included error messages as attached file generated by
> the validation check by Azure send grid for SMTP.

You can send email via SendGrid from your same python Azure Function using
[SendGrid binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=python). But function binding does not support attaching file in mail. For that you can write [custom code using SendGrid SDK](https://www.twilio.com/blog/sending-email-attachments-with-twilio-sendgrid-python) instead of using inbuilt binding.

> I didn't know that function bindind does not supprt attaching file.
> I try to use sendgrid SDK and API

> SendGrid API
> Should I also see the reference like below link ?
> [attachments](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/migrating-from-v2-to-v3-mail-send/#attachments)

Yes you can. I believe that's REST API spec. If you use the SendGrid SDK, that will take care of it for you.

> If there is no problem with the validation check, copy that file to
> SQL database table.

Do you mean keeping the file as binary in some SQL table column? Though you can technically store that in varbinary type column. But I would recommend to store the blob link instead of storing the whole file in SQL. You can use [SQL activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure) in your pipeline to call a stored proc passing the blob link as param.

> My comment had included miss word. the below is right.
> If there is no problem with the validation check, copy the information in file to SQL database table becase I need to analysis the data after my accumulation of data.
> I can not know that How to set the trigger of migration process to SQL database.
> Is it better that I  use  that message queue of copy complete of Strage blob as output ?.

As mentioned above, you won't need custom queue since Data Factory already has [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger) to help you.

Comment: Please check answers for follow up questions inline.

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is clear. I'll try again.
I appreciate your advice.